Quarkus Vertx EventBus Uni<Class> Return custom HTTP Code
I am using Quarkus 3.9.2 and Quarkus Vertx fully reactive with EventBus using @ConsumeEvent
I have the controller look like this
@Inject
EventBus bus;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/path/{id}")
public Uni<People> getPeopleById(@PathParam("id") String id){
   JsonObject req = new JsonObject();
   req.put("id", id);
   return bus.<People>request("getPeopleById", req, new DeliveryOptions().setSendTimeout(12000L)))
         .onItem().transform(Message::body)
         .ifNoItem().after(Duration.ofMilis(12000L))
         .failWith(new Exception("Error Service"));
}

I have the service look like this
@ConsumeEvent("getPeopleById")
public void getPeopleById(Message message){
   JsonObject req = (JsonObject) message.body();
   if("1".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getString("id")){
      message.reply(new Jsonobject(new Peopl()));
   }else {
      FailObject failObject = new FailObject();
      failObject.setStatus(400);
      failObject.setMessage("Error no data found");
      failObject.setField1("data field1");
      failObject.setField2("data field2");
      message.fail(500, Json.encode(failObject));
   }
}

I want to make a custom return http status code, for example if there is no data received, I should return HttpCode 400 or other HttpCode with custom object
{"status":400, "message":"Error no data found", "field1":"data field1", "field2":"data field2"}

The problem is, everytime there is an error to my service or throw Exception, it always return as HttpCode 500 with data looks like this (I think this is default error object)
{"details":"Error id xxxxxxxxxx", "stack":"(RECIPIENT_FAILURE_500) xxxxxxxx")


I found a way to handle the error, but I need to adjust my Service
@ConsumeEvent("getPeopleById")
public void getPeopleById(Message message){
   JsonObject req = (JsonObject) message.body();
   if("1".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getString("id")){
      message.reply(new Jsonobject(new People()));
   }else {
      message.fail(400, "Error 400";
   }
}

After that I adjust my Controller to process onFailure event
@Inject
EventBus bus;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/path/{id}")
public Uni<People> getPeopleById(@PathParam("id") String id){
   JsonObject req = new JsonObject();
   req.put("id", id);
   return bus.<People>request("getPeopleById", req, new DeliveryOptions().setSendTimeout(12000L)))
         .onItem().transform(Message::body)
         .onFailure().recoverWithUni(er -> {
             FailObject failObject = new FailObject();
             failObject.setStatus(400);
             failObject.setMessage("Error no data found");
             failObject.setField1("data field1");
             failObject.setField2("data field2");
             if("Error 400".equalsIgnoreCase(er.getMessage()){
                 return Uni.createForm().item(Response.status(400).entity(Json.encode(failObject)).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
             }else{
                 return Uni.createForm().item(Response.serverError().entity(new People()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
             }
         }
         .ifNoItem().after(Duration.ofMilis(12000L))
         .failWith(new Exception("Error Service"));
}

